# OBJ file in surface3d

Tags: c++, qt, qml, wavefront

I have new problem couldnt find any solution in Google ...
im using a qml file and it contain a surface3d , when i show it with a obj file that was in qt examples (oilrig) it could show correct without any problems!

but when i used my own obj file (boat) it couldnt show correct in surface3d application (showing with grid Triangles, not like a volume ...)

[image: my own .obj (wavefront export) file]
[image: .obj (wavefront export) file from qt examples]

in blender(a program for editing 3d models) my boat and oilrig has correct views  but in surface3d just oilrig is true!
i tested 100 items more that downloaded from internet but cant work , just oilrig that was from qt examples was true
can any one help me????

Comment: looks like you have some problems with normals. try to clear scaling/rotating (Ctrl-A) in Blender and check the model normals.

Comment: i dont know whats your meaning ,Im not blender'user ... i just needed a obj 3d model for my surface3d and i found this obj from internet , i tried Ctrl+A in blender but it dont work when i uncheck rotation and scale and exporting again. what can i do mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found a Temporary solution that was usefull for me.

1- convert that model in blender to ".dae"

2- upload it in [scene editor online](https://clara.io/)

3-convert it to Model (from NULL)

4-export as .obj file and use it in QT ^_^